# ShowCamera with paint module

Tags: android, module, paint, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Paint module doesn't work properly after using camera - even opening camera without any further action will cause this issue-, I know it's weird, but I It was working fine with old titanium SDKs.

I'm using SDK 5.1.1, android 4.4, tested it's working fine on device with android 4.3, only 4.4 and higher.

here's a sample of my test code

```
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success : function(event) {
        Ti.API.info('success');
    },
    cancel : function() {
        Ti.API.info('cancel');
    },
    error : function(error) {
        Ti.API.info('error');
    },
    //allowEditing : false,
    saveToPhotoGallery : true
});
```

---

```
var Paint = require('ti.paint');
paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
    top : 10,
    right : 10,
    bottom : 10,
    left : 10,
    backgroundColor : "#fff",
    strokeColor : '#000',
    strokeAlpha : 255,
    strokeWidth : 10,
    eraseMode : false

});
paintView.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('flagStart');
});
```

here's how it looks after using camera, the writing is choppy.!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LQ12.jpg

Comment: So what exactly is going on? You say 'doesn't work properly' but that doesn't give anything to replicate or test.

Comment: here's how it looks after using camera, the writing is choppy.!!
https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=IMG_20160210_092743.jpg

Comment: BTW, link above doesn't show anything.